# How to understand below java fx code

Tags: javafx

I am trying to understand this code. How many times does this code repeat? This code makes my application resizable. I think the `start` function is executed only at the start, so how is this code being executing repeatedly?

```
public void start( Stage stage ) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource("Content.fxml" ));
    Region contentRootRegion = (Region) loader.load();

    //Set a default "standard" or "100%" resolution
    double origW = 960;
    double origH = 540;

    //If the Region containing the GUI does not already have a preferred width and height, set it.
    //But, if it does, we can use that setting as the "standard" resolution.
    if ( contentRootRegion.getPrefWidth() == Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE )
        contentRootRegion.setPrefWidth( origW );
    else
        origW = contentRootRegion.getPrefWidth();

    if ( contentRootRegion.getPrefHeight() == Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE )
        contentRootRegion.setPrefHeight( origH );
    else
        origH = contentRootRegion.getPrefHeight();

    //Wrap the resizable content in a non-resizable container (Group)
    Group group = new Group( contentRootRegion );
    //Place the Group in a StackPane, which will keep it centered
    StackPane rootPane = new StackPane();
    rootPane.getChildren().add( group );

    stage.setTitle( "My Slide" );
    //Create the scene initally at the "100%" size
    Scene scene = new Scene( rootPane, origW, origH );
    //Bind the scene's width and height to the scaling parameters on the group
    group.scaleXProperty().bind( scene.widthProperty().divide( origW ) );
    group.scaleYProperty().bind( scene.heightProperty().divide( origH ) );
    //Set the scene to the window (stage) and show it
    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. The code gets executed every time `start(...)` is invoked. If this is the `start(...)` method in your `Application` subclass, then it gets invoked once by the FX runtime at startup. It would also get invoked if you called it directly, but that is not common in that scenario (and you probably shouldn't call it directly). Why do you think the code is "repeated"?

Comment: The probability of getting an answer in SO is proportional to the square of certainity of the question asked. Please be more specific and make the problem clear so that other users can easily help especially and exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: `Content.fxml` could cause any code to be executed, when it's loaded. All we know is that the object loaded is of type `Region`.

Comment: I mean How many times is this code executed. This code scale automatically gui when I resize this application. So I am frustrated. start cannot be a update function. Am I wrong? But how then this code is executed every time I resize application?

Comment: It is not executed every time you resize the application; it is (probably, it's impossible to tell without the full context) executed only once. TheGUI automatically scales because you call the `bind` method on the `scaleX` and `scaleY` properties.

Comment: Thank you very much. So bind keep properties syncronized